# Python: Como escribir en un archivo JSON en un lugar especifico (o sea, especificando el index de lista etc.)

Tags: python, json

Tengo el siguiente archivo JSON:

```
[
    {
        "a":"1",
        "b":["2", "3"]
    },
    {
        "a":"11",
        "b":["4","5"]
    }
]
```

Y quiero agregar desde mi archivo python un nuevo objeto, y que quede algo así

```
[
    {
        "a":"1",
        "b":["2", "3"]
    },
    {
        "a":"11",
        "b":["4","5"]
    },
    {
        "a":"31",
        "b":["53", "23"]
    }
]
```

He intentado con:

```
import json

data = {"a":"31", "b":["53", "23"]}

with open(f'test.json', 'r') as r:
            jsondata = r.read()

with open('test.json', 'w') as jsonfile:
    jsonfile.write(jsondata[:-1])
    jsonfile.write(',')
    json.dump(data, jsonfile)
```

Y otros pero no funcionan, y no encontre en la pagina de json ayuda ni tampoco acá en stackoverflow. Reitero, lo que quiero hacer es añadir un diccionario dentro de un archivo json, pero no con append, mas en un lugar en especifico. Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa json.load, eso te cargará las partes del json segun [una tabla de conversión](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders) Entre ellos convierte los objects en diccionarios y los array en listas.

Teniendo una lista, es tan simple como usar el método insert que nos permite insertar un item en una lista en una posicion especifica:

```
import json

data = {"a":"31", "b":["53", "23"]}

with open("hola.json") as file:
    # cargo el json a partir del archivo
    # en este caso particular esto devuelve una lista de diccionarios
    jsondata = json.load(file)
# inserto en la posicion 1 los datos extra
jsondata.insert(1, data)

with open('test.json', 'w') as jsonfile:
    # guardo el json en el archivo "test.json"
    json.dump(jsondata, jsonfile)
```

Puedes aprender más del modulo json leyendo la [documentación oficial](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/json.html)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Lo entendí perfectamente, gracias por las referencias también, muy completo.

Comment: De nada compañero c: